# texto de formulario ser adcionado como link

Tags: php, link

Gostaria de saber Como definir o link através de um formulario
ex:
tenho um campo a ser preenchido, o que for preenchido nesse campo te que abrir no link
se for preenchido 1234, o link tem que ser www.exemplo.com.br/1234, se for preenchido 12424 o link que for abrir tem que ser o www.exemplo.com.br/12424

Comment: Porque da tag PHP? O que se deve fazer no PHP?

Comment: Se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e veja porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Outro post que poderá lhe ajudar a obter melhores respostas nas suas próximas perguntas é https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `jquery` para fazer isso, fiz correndo mas creio que vai funcionar:

Você coloca esse script no seu `index.php` ou cria um arquivo **.js** (não esqueça de retirar a tag `<script>` e `</script>` para isso) e referencia no seu `index` que também funciona.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#botao").click(function () {
    var pegalink = document.getElementById('link').value;
      window.open("teste2.php/" + pegalink);
        });
 });
</script>
```

E adiciona isso no seu `index.php`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="link" id="link">
<input type="button" id="botao" name="botao">
```

E então é só trocar o link do `window.open` para a página que quer atribuir os valores na URL(`enviado.php`, por exemplo) e os meus values que estão nos campos do script e dos inputs pelos seus que funciona normal.

Answer (score 1):

Concatene o valor da entrada com a variável Url.

```js
    $(function () {
        $('#button').on('click', function () {
            var text = $('#text');
            var Url='www.exemplo.com.br/';
            text.val(Url + text.val() );  
            //para funcionar corretamente add http:// aqui ou na var URL
            window.open("http://"+text.val());  
        });
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="" id="text" style="width: 250px;" />
    
<button type="button" id="button" name="button">Enviar</button>
```